# How to display all Availability Zone in terrafor output?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

Recently I have started exploring terraform. I wanted to list all Availability Zone in region in output terminal. The code is :-

```
resource "aws_subnet" "main" {
count = "${length(data.aws_availability_zones.azs.names)}"
vpc_id     = "${aws_vpc.example.cidr_block}"
cidr_block = "10.0.1.0/24"
availability_zone = "${data.aws_availability_zones.azs.names[count.index]}"  
 tags = {
  Name = "Main" 
    }
   }
  output "list_of_az" {
  value = "aws_subnet.main.availability_zone[*]"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure to understand the difference between string literals [1] and references to exported attribute(s) from the resources [2]. The way you are currently trying to get the output means it will output `aws_subnet.main.availability_zone[*]` as a string literal. To make sure you get the values you just need to remove the double quotes from the start and the end of the string literal:

```
output "list_of_az" {
  value = aws_subnet.main[*].availability_zone
}
```

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/strings

[2] https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/references

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to display all the Availability Zones in a region, you don't necessary need to iterate over your subnets you have created. You simply display the names from the `data.aws_availability_zones`:

```hcl
data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {
  state = "available"
}

output "list_of_az" {
  value = data.aws_availability_zones.available[*].names
}
```

This will output something like:

```
list_of_az = [
  tolist([
    "us-east-1a",
    "us-east-1b",
    "us-east-1c",
    "us-east-1d",
    "us-east-1e",
    "us-east-1f",
  ]),
]
```

Obviously, the output will depend on your current region.